# Date fiIter Issues in LINQ

Tags: linq, date

I have an ASPX page that collects 5 optional search criteria from a user and returns the result in a grid. Once the criteria are collected and the view button clicked, the code behind generates the filter like we have below

```
// aSearchCriteria is a class that holds the criteria
...
string filter = string.Empty;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aSearchCriteria.RegistrationNumber)) filter =
        "f.BusinessRegistrationNumber = '" + 
        aSearchCriteria.BusinessRegistrationNumber + "'";
if (aSearchCriteria.ChangedStartDate != null && aSearchCriteria.ChangedEndDate != null)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
   {
       filter += " && f.ChangedDate >= '" +
                 aSearchCriteria.ChangedStartDate.ToShortDateString()  + 
                          "' && f.ChangedDate <= '" +
                aSearchCriteria.ChangedEndDate.ToShortDateString() + "'";
   }
   else
   {
       ...
   }
}
...

Using (CustomerEntities db = new CustomerEntities())
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        filter = "f => " + filter;
        **return db.Customers.Where(filter).ToList();**
    }
    else
    ...
 }
 ...
```

Sample:

```
 "filter" value: f => f.ChangedDate > '01/01/2012' && f.ChangedDate < '14/01/2012'
```

Anytime I execute this I get this error message:

> The query syntax is not valid. Near term '>', line 6, column 5.

Comment: Are you using [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to make the filter a string.  What you should do instead is apply the filtering to the IQueryable you get.  Something like:

```
var customers = db.Customers.AsQueryable();

if (aSearchCriteria.ChangedStartDate != null && aSearchCriteria.ChangedEndDate != null)
{
    customers = customers
        .Where(c => c.ChangedDate >= aSearchCriteria.ChangedStartDate &&
                    c.ChangedDate >= aSearchCriteria.ChangedEndDate);
}

// ... apply other filters as necessary

return customers.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks.

I forgot to add that the application employs a 3-tier architecture: UI (aspx) <> BL (Web Service) <> DA (EF, Classes). The Criteria comes from the UI and the DA returns the customer(s) object based on the criteria.
Based on the scenario painted, Can the snippet above work (Data Contract)? 

if yes, wouldn't the code am going to write become very long considering the fact that I could have one, or some, or all the five criteria specified at the same time ((1,,,,5)^5) lines of condition expression.

Comment: how do the expressions combine?  assuming 'and', then you'll just have  1 .Where() added for each expression (conditional on whether that filter is 'enabled' or not).  If it's 'or' instead, you'll generate the 1 to 5 inputs and then union/distinct them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ObjectQuery.Where(string)
the string predicate should look like

```
"it.ChangedDate > '01/01/2012' && it.ChangedDate < '14/01/2012'"
```

(no f=> and the alias of the table is it)

Please confirm it helped :)